# Inconsistent tick labels font with matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex, subplot

I'm making a grid of plots using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`, and I want the tick labels to be in LaTeX's sans-serif font, but when I do use subplots I always get at least one tick label rendered in matplotlib's default font.

Here's a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x)
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='sans-serif')
plt.show()
```

If you comment out the `fig, axes = plt.subplots` line, the tick labels display as they should.

I'm using python version 3.6.0 and matplotlib version 2.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to the rcParams should always be made as soon as possible and necessarily before the objects they affect are created.

Thus, putting the rc changes at the top, resolves the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='sans-serif')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Follow up question (and thanks for the answer): why wouldn't `plt.text` or `plt.xlabel` show up in LaTeX font? Assuming the program is otherwise the same as that in your asnwer.

Comment: In my case they do. The problem for me seems rather that the ticklabels do not obey to the sans-serif property.